# finding similar value

Tags: matlab, scatter

i want to find multiplication that give the same value (of x-axis and y-axis) when plotted in graph.
is there any easiest way to find in?
i have used find but matlab told me that the argument is wrong.

```
 for i = 1:size(B,1)
        p1 =  A * B(1,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
        dtransformation0a(i) = d*p1;
        qtransformation0a(i) = q*p1;
        p2 =  A * B(2,:)' -A * B(i,:)'
        dtransformation0b(i) = d*p2;
        qtransformation0b(i) = q*p2;
         p3 =  A * B(3,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
        dtransformation0c(i) = d*p3;
        qtransformation0c(i) = q*p3;
Nx=length(dp);          
Ny=length(qp);         

for i=1:Nx
If dp(i)=qp(i)
samevalue=dp(i)
Nsamevalue=i
end


    figure
     scatter(dtransformation0a,qtransformation0a,100,'b.')          
     hold on 
     scatter(dtransformation0b,qtransformation0b,100,'b.')
      hold on 
     scatter(dtransformation0c,qtransformation0c,100,'b.')
    hold on
```

Comment: Nobody answered your first question in minutes, so you had to ask it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you need from your question, this?

```
indexes = find(dtransformation0a == dtransformation0b & ...
               qtransformation0a == qtransformation0b & ...
               dtransformation0a == dtransformation0c & ...
               qtransformation0a == qtransformation0c);

sameValuesX = dtransformation0a(indexes);
sameValuesY = qtransformation0a(indexes);

scatter(sameValuesX, sameValuesY);
```

Comment: i dont want to put it in graph. i just want to find the multiplication that give the same value of x-axis and y-axis. sorry for making you haywire with my question

Comment: multiplication of what?

Comment: multiplication of every d and q with those p (p1,p2 and p3) or do you have email. i can send the full coding to you.